# An example of solving nonlinear partial differential equation using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was trying to solve a nonlinear partial differential equation using mathematica, but mathematica didn't provide a solution:

[image]

Did I make any mistake in the formation? or is it because the equation is too complicate?

Comment: no chance there is an analytic solution to such thing.

Comment: @agentp I did get a special kind of solution... But I was wondering whether there are other kind of solutions.

Comment: I guess I should qualify, there are trivial/degenerate solutions such as `f=constant`. Mathematica only seeks general solutions and does not report special cases. If you are after those you need to approach the problem as you would by hand, making trial substitutions and observing if the equation reduces to something solvable.

Comment: @agentp In fact the special kind solution I found is f(x^(-3/2)y) for any smooth function $f$. But I was wondering whether this is the only kind of explicit solution.

Comment: @agentp I don't understand why mathematica didn't find the solution that I found.